# Trouble with gulp "Task 'default' is not found in your gulpfile"

Tags: node.js, gulp

I believe my error is because I gulp is referencing the wrong gulpfile.js as I have two files located in the below locations:

./gulpfile.js

/home/alv4/projects/everycheese/gulpfile.js

Prior to this error:
I had  trouble installing gulp.

I have  gulp installed globally npm install gulp -g
 and
 in the vitrualenv

I started by resolving issue realted to "/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory" when attempting to run gulp. I believe this has been sloved by: sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node which I found instructions for at: http://mattseymour.net/blog/2015/01/usrbinenv-node-no-such-file-or-directory/

Then  using touch gulpfile.js

Now I am receiving the error:
"Using gulpfile.js"
"Task 'default' is not on your gulpfile"

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Is there a `gulp.task('default'...)` in gulpfile in the directory you're running `gulp` from?

Comment: The original error regarding task was because I was running it from the wrong directory.  Now when I run it from /home/alv4/projects/everycheese/gulpfile.js  I receive a cannot find module 'gulp-sass. No gulpfile.js located in /home/alv4/projects/everycheese/ does not have gulp.task('default'...) in it.

Thanks for your help. Any ideas?

Comment: That error is saying your gulpfile.js doesn't include a task called "default." And that's right, it doesn't. Check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39678723/1241736. I'm guessing you're running `gulp` and your gulpfile does include _some_ task, in which case you need to run `gulp nameOfYourTaskGoesHere`. But that answer explains it and also has a link to a good intro guide

Comment: // Default task
gulp.task('default', function() {
    runSequence(['styles', 'scripts', 'imgCompression'], 'runServer', 'browserSync');
});

Comment: Sorry having trouble with the enter key the gulpfile.js located in /home/alv4/projects/everycheese/gulpfile.js  contains // Default task gulp.task('default', function() { runSequence(['styles', 'scripts', 'imgCompression'], 'runServer', 'browserSync'); });

Comment: The gulpflie.js located at the root has nothing it's empty.

Comment: The only relevant gulpfile is the one in the directory you're running the command in. You're in `/home/alv4/projects/everycheese/` and run `gulp` and get `task 'default' is not in your gulpfile`?

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I executed the gulp command from the /home/alv4/projects/everycheese/ directory and it gets beyond the gulpfile.js file not found error. I am receiving another error now regarding cannot find module 'gulp-sass' but that is not the original intent of the post so I will start a new thread... I guess.  Thank you for helping. It is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Problem solved regarding the gulp-sass error. I needed to install NPM in virtual env